# While php не работает

Tags: php

```html
$i=1
    while($i<100){
            echo $i;
            echo " ";
        if($i%5==0){
                echo "<br>";
        }
        $i++
    }
```

или

```
$i=1
    do{
        
            echo $i;
            echo " ";
        if($i%5==0){
                echo "<br>";
        }
        $i++
    
    }
    while($i<100)
```

Comment: у Вас не хватает ; перед `$i=1` и `$i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас пропущена точка с запятой перед `$i=1` и `$i++`

Попробуйте так:

```
$i=1;
while($i<100){
   echo $i, ' ';
 
   if($i%5===0){
       echo "<br>";
   }
   $i++;
 }
```

Comment: а вот после js это непривично)

Comment: @Мнебезсахара даже в js правила хорошего тона отделять конструкции точкой с запятой